# Best Way to Secure a Backend API - Angular

Tags: angular, laravel, api, security

Currently, I'm developing an angular app that uses a Laravel backend for all the server related tasks. I make use of the API routes in laravel for most of things, and those routes are secured by Bearer Tokens. For each API Call, the browser calls the Apache server, which by using a reverse proxy, redirects the requests to API Host (In another port). Then, a middleware checks the Token and its validity. Also, the API has already SSL Implemented.

**However, I feel still concerned about multiple API Calls attacks. A user could take the JWT Token from a request inspection in the browser and then make several requests with a script before the token expires. The API has also a rate-limiting.**

What could be the best way to secure this? Laravel secures that by default using a CSRF Token when it uses the default Blade Template Engine. This would be the correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSRF (Cross Site Request Forgery) should protect you from other site performing a malicious activity on a url if user has already logged in into your side and you are managing token in cookies. But the case you are talking about, if your user is that smart that he is taking your jwt token from cookie. Then he can very well also copy your xsrf token. The answer you are looking for is :-

**Proper cross origin policy (CORS), so his script can't hit your api.**

Also browser also stops user making too many concurrent requests parallely on a single domain. At max it allows 6 calls at a time to go to server and after 6 others keep in pending until some api returns with response.

**After having proper CORS setup, you should be done.**

Other parameters related to performance like where to limit or scale it depends on your choice and application.